# Use Alt+Shift LMB in Maya for Pan

Tags: maya, hotkeys

I'm new to Maya, just started after the last extension, I used to play with Modo.
So I want to customize the navigation shortcuts, but I can't find anything in the hotkeys window, any help?
And I would also like to summon the RMB tool list with the spacebar.

Comment: No this is hardwired theres no way to change it. For some reason each and every 3d application wants to have their own shortcuts. You'd think that eventually they would clash with each other but ive seen at least 24 ways to do this by now. Dont worry you will learn switching very quickly.

Comment: @joojaa Not if I don't have a 3-button mouse, no. Have they ever thought about people that use laptop? even the `Slide Edge` tool doesn't work with LMB, this is ridiculous and it's not just a question of stubborn attitudes.

Comment: No they have not thought of laptops, you couldnt even get certified gear for laptops for a long time. Maya used to be a software that you bought your system for not the other way around.

Comment: if its any consolation the rmb tool list could be bound to spacebar if you want to lose mayas niftiest feature. Anyway buy a mouse with 3 buttons or click your mouse wheel.

Comment: @joojaa I mapped the `Track View` tool to `Ctrl + Shift + Space`. Thanks, maybe I'll look for some emulation software if I don't get used.

Answer (score 0):

This is still locked and unchangeable in 2018 Maya.

Small consolation, you can change 3ds Max to act like Maya. So you only need to learn the one way.

Or commit one way to muscle memory... if you're coming from 3ds Max to Maya.

Horrid. How it can be changed in 3ds Max but not in Maya... that's an interesting question.

Answer (score -1):

Maya Menus->Window->Settings/Preferences->Hotkey Editor->Navigation. Change what ever you want there.

Comment: The Hotkey Editor only allows you to set simple keyshortcuts, and not mouse navigation shortcuts.